# Number of checked checked boxes with lambda function

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda

I am trying to find the number of checked checkboxes in a gridview in WPF. I have searched tried a few things and as a result, I think this should work but I get an error.

Here is my code.

```
var checkedBoxes = WorkCenterGrid.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(mo => mo.IsChecked = true);
```

I have tried adding `(CheckBox)` before `mo` but it also didn't work.

This asked for just personel development and understand the error.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two equal signs in the `Count()` to make it an equality comparison.

```
var checkedBoxes = WorkCenterGrid.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(mo => mo.IsChecked == true);
```

Comment: :) I have actually tried this but I guess I was getting an error for something else. Thanks. :)